# How do I change the usage of a device_fragment?

Tags: sybase-ase, sybase-ase-15.7

As can be seen below an index `device_fragment` usage is log only when it should be data only, and a log `device_fragmen`t usage is data only when it should be log only.

```
 name     db_size       owner    dbid created      durability lobcomplvl inrowlen  status
 -------- ------------- -------- ---- ------------ ---------- ---------- --------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 a0000023    76000.0 MB a0000023    4 Sep 05, 2017 full                0      NULL select into/bulkcopy/pllsort, trunc log on chkpt, allow nulls by default


 device_fragments               size          usage                created                   free kbytes
 ------------------------------ ------------- -------------------- ------------------------- ----------------
 a0000023_data000                    250.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                     86
 a0000023_index000                   500.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    126
 a0000023_log000                     100.0 MB log only             Sep  6 2017  9:37AM       not applicable
 a0000023_data000                    500.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                     56
 a0000023_index000                   500.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                   2554
 a0000023_data000                    300.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                     70
 a0000023_index000                   700.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    422
 a0000023_data000                   1000.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    126
 a0000023_index000                  1000.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_log000                     548.5 MB log only             Sep  6 2017  9:37AM       not applicable
 a0000023_log000                       0.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    272
 a0000023_log000                       1.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_data000                   2449.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    112
 a0000023_data000                      2.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_index000                  2422.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                     84
 a0000023_index000                     0.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_index000                     3.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_data000                   2997.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    322
 a0000023_data000                      4.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_index000                  1995.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    658
 a0000023_index000                     0.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    510
 a0000023_index000                     5.0 MB log only             Sep  6 2017  9:37AM       not applicable
 a0000023_log000                     345.5 MB log only             Sep  6 2017  9:37AM       not applicable
 a0000023_log000                       0.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_log000                       4.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_index000                  1495.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    602
 a0000023_index000                     0.5 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_index000                     5.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_data000                   5495.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    518
 a0000023_data000                      5.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_index000                  1620.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                     28
 a0000023_index000                     5.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_data000                   6995.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                 352250
 a0000023_data000                      3.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                      0
 a0000023_index000                  7747.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                   1638
 a0000023_data000                   6000.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                    140
 a0000023_index000                  2000.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                     56
 a0000023_data000                   4000.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                     98
 a0000023_index000                 15000.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM                6856024
 a0000023_data000                  10000.0 MB data only            Sep  6 2017  9:37AM               10200000

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 log only free kbytes = 1018706
```

Comment: While we can certainly guess which fragments you're referring to (eg, based on the name of the device), to minimize any confusion you should explicitly state which fragments you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can use the `sp_dropsegment` stored proc to remove a database segment from a database device; this will eliminate all **future** allocations for the segment from being made against the device; any space the segment currently uses on the device will remain in place until moved elsewhere, eg:

```
use a0000023
go
sp_dropsegment 'logsegment','a0000023','a0000023_index000'
go
```

- remove all **future** allocations for the `logsegment` segment from the `a0000023_index000` device fragment
- any log pages currently residing on this device fragment will remain in place until a) new log space has been allocated on another device fragment and b) the log has been successfully truncated

Assuming you want to remove non-`logsegment` segments from the `a0000023_log000` device, you'll need to find the names of all said segments; this can be found by running the `sp_helpdb` stored proc from within the database, eg:

```
use a0000023
go
sp_helpdb a0000023
go
```

- in addition to the normal output from `sp_helpdb`, the above should also provide a detailed list of the segments that reside on each device fragment

Once you determine the names of the non-`logsegment` segments that reside on a device fragment, you can remove future allocations via the `sp_dropsegment` stored proc.

Assuming you want to remove the `default` and `system` segments from the `a0000023_log000` device:

```
use a0000023
go
sp_dropsegment 'default','a0000023','a0000023_log000'
go
sp_dropsegment 'system' ,'a0000023','a0000023_log000'
go
```

- remove all **future** allocations for the `default` and `system` segments from the `a0000023_log000` device fragment
- any data/index/system-table data currently residing on this device fragment will remain in place until said data is moved (eg, drop/recreate index; reorg rebuild a table)

Other system procedures that can be used to manage segment/device mappings:

- `sp_addsegment` : create a new database segment on a database device currently in use by the database
- `sp_extendsegment` : extend a current database segment onto a database device currently in use by the database